# We could not send an IPN due to an HTTP error: 400: Bad Request

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, yii2

I'm using PayPal's script from

```
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php
```

To create IPN. I'm using Yii2 framework, but I think it is not the problem. In my sandbox account I'm trying to test IPN but I'm keep getting error:

```
We could not send an IPN due to an HTTP error: 400: Bad Request
```

Not sure what is causing error because I can access ipn url of my site successfully. Url for IPN is

```
http://backend.trbovic.info/subscription/ipn
```

It is not cookie problem because I tried to use different browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding:

```
public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

To my XYZController

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by simply moving the IPN listener to the root of my server (`www.example.com/ipn.php`). Everything worked fine after that.